# Single Axis Simulation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, simulation

Hi i wanted to generate a single axis graph (dont know if this is called a graph exactly) in matlab something like this

[image]

In the above image the numerical values represent time ( 1 till 23) min and the vertical thin black lines represent event A . Some of the vertical black lines have a red circle on top denoting occurrence of an event B along with the event A. Is it possible to generate such a simulated image in matlab ? If so what keywords should i look for. Any suggestions to get me quickly started on generating such a graph/Simulation. (Note: I havent actually used matlab a lot.. certainly never generated graphs in it)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a [stem graph](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/stem.html), and then do something like:

```
stem(event_times, ones(size(event_times));
```

You can overlay multiple graphs to get the red circles, etc.

Comment: So i checked the Stem command out and i am having difficulty working the command stem((12,13,14,15),1) to work. I expect vertical lines on 12,13,14 and 15 upto a magnitude of 1 but its not working.. any suggestions ??

Comment: @Rajeshwar: Use `stem([12 13 14 15], ones(1,4))`.  You can use `xlim([min max])` to set the limits of the x-axis.

Comment: So I think I almost have it. I am using the command stem([12 13 14 15], ones(1,4),'filled') however how could i alter this command so that only 12 and 14 (vertical magnitude lines) are circled and not all of the lines.

Comment: @Rajeshwar: As I suggested in my question, you can simply plot two stem graphs on top of each other (one for the non-circle points, and the other for the circled points).  You will need to use `hold on` in order to have both plots displayed simultaneously.